# I want to find out the length of Dropzone

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I am new here i came up the issue i am using dropzone for file upload on button click it gives me length is undefined. Please help me solve my issue. When i remove ready function it is not working properly thats why i kept document ready function. here is my code below html and ready function and ajax call function.

> HTML

```
  <form action="#" class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
                    <div class="fallback">
                        <input name="file" id="fileupload" type="file" multiple="multiple">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

> On Load Function`

```
$(function () {

   $('#dropzone').dropzone();

});
```

> AJAX Call

```
        var imagedata = new FormData();
   var fileUpload = document.getElementById("dropzone").files.length;
   // var countfiles = $('#dropzone').files;
   // alert(countfiles);
   for (var i = 0; i < fileUpload; i++) {
        var filname = document.getElementById("dropzone").files[i];
        imagedata.append("FileName", filname);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of dropzone like this one:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});
```

Then you can access all files in the dropzone, using `myDropzone.files`.

To get

all accepted files: `.getAcceptedFiles()`
all rejected files: `.getRejectedFiles()`
all queued files: `.getQueuedFiles()`
all uploading files: `.getUploadingFiles()`